# Not getting the result with the updated fields

Tags: c#, mongodb

Why dont i get the result with the updated fields?

```
public async Task<bool> FindAndUpdate(FilterDefinition<T> filterDefinition, UpdateDefinition<T> updateDefinition)
{
    var result = await _collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filterDefinition, updateDefinition);
}
```

Comment: This is not enough to help people help you. Try adding more relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think your return type is wrong. You are using a `Task<bool>`, but the `FindOneAndUpdateAsync()` function returns a `TProjection`, so your return type should be a `Task<TProjection>`, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want mongodb to return the updated document instead of the default document you need to pass `new:true` along with your query.

> new   boolean     Optional.
>
> When true, returns the modified document rather than the original. The findAndModify method ignores the new option for remove operations. The default is false.

[Link to the documentation of findAndModify](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/command/findAndModify/)

Does this help you?

Comment: allright it's a good info to tell from the beginning :)

A 'dumb way ?' would be to to do a findOne on your updated query to get it, but it costs you an extra request. I will try to find another way with 2.2.

Comment: seems to work with 2.2:

https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/